# spend or have an unforgettable weekend

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is it correct to say: 
I promise we are going to spend an unforgettable weekend.
Or
I promise we are going to have an unforgettable weekend
Or both are ok?

Comment: Normally when you use *spend* in this kind of construction, you follow it up with something else. *We are going to spend an unforgettable weekend* ***at the cottage***. You can follow *have* with something too, but it works better without something than does *spend*. That aside, both are fine.